# Div does not center inside Div

Tags: html, css

I am centering a number inside of a circle. I am trying to center that number in a "card"

```css
.numberCircle {
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

#inner {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div id="@(ViewBag.Id)" class="card-body" style="min-height: 495px;">
    <div style="text-align:center">
      <h2>My Number</h2>
    </div>
    <div id="inner">
      <div class="numberCircle" style="background:green;font-size:32px">2.98</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The heading centers but the number does not:
[image]

Comment: What have you done to try? I only see centering markup on the heading container. Maybe put your circle inside that.

Comment: Protip: for all our sakes, don't use inline styles. They're a royal pain. Put it in your CSS.

Comment: @isherwood - for my sake, I have to use an inline style here because the "color" actually will change based on the number and will come from the Model.  If you know how to do that without using an inline style, please share.

Comment: Fine, but you don't need to do that in your demo. :)

Comment: To answer what have I tried, I created the "inner" class to try to center, but it does not move all the way to the center.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `margin: 0 auto;` to `.numberCircle`. That will center it inside the `inner` div.

```css
.numberCircle {
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#inner {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div id="@(ViewBag.Id)" class="card-body" style="min-height: 495px;">
    <div style="text-align:center">
      <h2>My Number</h2>
    </div>
    <div id="inner">
      <div class="numberCircle" style="background:green;font-size:32px">2.98</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```